# Change object value after foreign key exception in Grails

Tags: grails

I can change a object property value after the exception error catch ? I do this in my delete action:

```
@Transactional
    def delete(Task task) {

        if (task == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }
        try{
            task.delete flush:true
        }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
            Task.withNewSession{
                def taskError = Task.get(task.id)
                taskError.deleted = true
                taskError.save()
            }
        }

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'task.label', default: 'Task'), task.id])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }
```

but I receive this error:

> 'ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block.'

---

I tried to do this service with a method to handle the exception:

```
@Transactional
class UtilService {
    def delete(Object domain) {
        if(domain?.properties?.containsKey('deleted')){
            domain.deleted = false
            domain.save(flush: true)
        }
    }
}
```

and on catch:

```
 @Transactional
        def delete(Task task) {
            ...
            try{
                task.delete flush:true
            }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
                utilService.delete(task)
            }
            ...
        }
```

but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move try/catch block to controller and make a new method in service which will handle your exception if it occurs.

Comment: I created a new service, but keep getting the same error.You can exemplify  how to do?

Comment: Did you use controller as I said before?

Comment: did you mean make something like that: [http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2014/05/grails-goodness-exception-methods-in.html](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2014/05/grails-goodness-exception-methods-in.html) ?
The action delete is inside the TaskController..